# Why do I get "No connection adapters were found for 'value'" in Python Twill

Tags: python, python-3.x, twill

I'm trying to automate a process for my classmates, with a python script that downloads from my university servers the marks that we get through the download of a PDF. Unfortunately, it turns out that I get an error when running this code :

```py
from twill.commands import *
go('https://login.unice.fr/login?service=http://ent.unice.fr/uPortal/Login')


ids = {}
ids["username"] = "my_username" # I hid it
ids["password"] = "my_password" # I hid it too


fv("1", "username", ids["username"])
fv("1", "password", ids["password"])


submit("submit")
```

I get the error message
`No connection adapters were found for '/login;jsessionid=(token_i_hid)?service=http://ent.unice.fr/uPortal/Login'`

I'm new to twill. If there is any other alternative to do what I intend, I'll take it without hesitation. But it would be nice to fix what's wrong with my code tho

Thank you in advance.